# C# - How to prevent expansion of Explorer navigation bar when opened from C# program

Tags: c#, navigationbar, windows-explorer

When I open windows explorer from c# using the following code the navigation bar keeps expanding to the current folder. I want to stop this.

```
    var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Users");
    Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxM2t.png)

Comment: Can you put a screen shot to describe what you mean by "expanding to the current folder" and explain better what the expected behavior is .. ?

Comment: I believe that function is handled as a global setting for Explorer, and cannot be changed for a single window.

Comment: Do you mean you want to open windows explorer without navigating to a folder, Like when you open My Computer or This PC?

Comment: I want to navigate to a folder but i dont want the navigation bar to expand to that folder

Comment: They're talking about the navigation pane on the left hand side, and how you can have it automatically expand and scroll to your current folder in the directory tree.

Comment: Out of curiosity I'm wondering why you're set on disabling this feature.

Comment: I cannot focus when the navigation pane keeps expanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to modify registry.

1. Set `NavPaneExpandToCurrentFolder` to `0`
2. Do whatever you want
3. Restore existing value of `NavPaneExpandToCurrentFolder`

Use following code to modify registry:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
```

```
const string key = @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced";
int enabled = 1; // 0 to disable
Registry.SetValue(key, "NavPaneExpandToCurrentFolder", enabled, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

Comment: Doesnt seem to make a change

Comment: When you change Folder Options > Automatically expand to current folder manually, changes occur in above registry. I think you need to restart windows explorer process to apply changes.

Comment: In the folder options , automatically expand to current folder is unchecked.